# Error while defining enum structure.

Tags: c#, enums

I am creating class like this with enum.

```
 public class D
    {
        enum e { "one","two","three"};
    }
```

It is giving **"identifier expected"** compilation error. Whats wrong in this. is there any another structure.

Comment: You can't do it like this. Enums are not strings. What is your intended purpose? I mean, what do you want to use this for? Give a code example of how you would want to use this.

Comment: Thank you all. Finally I got Enums are not supported to put members as strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes and try like this.

```
enum e{
one,
two,
three
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't have string enumerations in C#, for an example using attributes have a look at [this article at codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11130/String-Enumerations-in-C).

You need to define your enum like

```
enum e
{
  One, Two, Three
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error message. You need to identify each of the values in the enum e.g.

```
 enum e
 {
   One = 1,
   Two = 2,
   Three = 3
 }
```

Comment: Or: `One = 1, Two = 2`, etc.. +1

Comment: C# does not support string values for enum members.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class D
    {
        enum e { one = 1, two = 2, three = 3};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
enum e
{
   One = 1,
   Two = 2,
   Three = 3
}
```